# pointer to pointer confusion, and transfer of nodes between lists

Tags: c, pointers

I am driving myself mad with some code segment in C, and I hope for intervention. I have:

```
typedef struct node{
int value;    
node_t *next;
node_t *prev;
} node_t;

node_t current_node;     
node_t other_list;

void transfer(node_t **ipp) 
{
  if (*ipp == NULL)
  {
     *ipp = current_node;
     current_node->prev->next = current_node->next; 
  }
  else 
  {
    (*ipp)->next = current_node;
    ipp = &(*ipp)->next;
    current_node->prev->next = current_node->next;
  }
}

int main(void)
{
 int i;
 for(i= 0; i< 10; i++)
 {
   transfer(&other_list);
   current_node = current_node->next;
 }
```

shouldnt I now be able to remove items from the first list and transfer them to the second? shouldnt also the other_list point at the last node inserted?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about your question ? What are you expecting to happen ? What's happening instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. You are updating the the "next" pointer of the previous node in the list but not the "prev" pointer of the next node in the list.
2. You aren't checking that the the current node actually points to another element in the list. `current_node->prev` could well be `null`.

Comment: sorry to both of you. I havent mentioned that current_node is one node in a ring of nodes. My goal is to remove all of these nodes, one by one, by transfering them to the other_list node. I would expect that other_list always points to the last node inserted. My printout suggests that I can transfer several nodes, but not all and that other_list always points to the first node inserted.

Comment: Thank you. I guess that I have to add (after the current_node->prev->next = ...) current_node->prev->next->prev = current_node->prev.